# Remove Disabled Accounts from all Groups that begin with “Group-”

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to Remove all Disabled Accounts from all Groups that begin with `Group-`. We have several Distribution groups that begin with `Groups-` for example `Groups-users-internal`, `groups-users-external` and many more.
I have a script but I get the message:

```
Remove-ADGroup : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '(name=Groups-sites-*)'.
At line:1 char:139
+ Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter “(name=Groups-sites-*)” | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser ...
```

so far my script is as follows
Please help

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter “(name=Groups-sites-*)” | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser | Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $False} | 
ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroup -Identity -LDAPFilter “(name=Groups-sites-*)” -Members $ -Confirm:$False}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will reply based on my experience with PoSh version 3:

To begin with, there is a slight syntax error in your code.  At char 139 you have {Remove-ADGroup..   The correct syntax is 'Remove-ADGroupMember'.

Remove-ADGroupMember does not have a -ldapfilter switch.  In this case, you will have to split your code up into a few lines as you will need to 'get' each object and 'process' each object consecutively or one item at a time.

```
# Using -whatif switch.  ** Remove whatif switch only when happy with desired result.
# Assumptions - all group members are users. Use Try{}Catch{} to handle errors.
# 

# Collect all groups into array
$groups = (Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(name=Group-*)").name

# Process each group one at a time
ForEach($group in $groups){

    # Get all members
    $members=Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group;

    # Process disabled accounts for removal
    $members | ForEach{
        If($_.enabled -eq $false){

            #Output member to be removed to screen
            $_ | Select Name,SAMAccountName,Enabled;

            #Remove disabled member from group
            Remove-ADGroupMember -identity $group -Members $_.samaccountname -confirm:$false -whatif

        } 

    } # Next Member

} # Next Group
```